# SQL Server 2016 Standard AlwaysOn group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In my SQL Server, I can’t see that options (Basic Availability Group, Database level health Detection, Per DatabaseDTC Suport) at New Availability Group – Specifiyname. I just see to write the [Availability group name].

So, when I execute New Availability Group Wizard, it didn't succeed.

This is the error:

> The specified command is invalid because the Always On Availability Groups join availability group (basic) feature is not supported by this edition of SQL Server.

[image]

Comment: Well, just **read the error message!** - *The specified command is invalid because the Always On Availability Groups join availability group (basic) feature **is not supported by this edition** of SQL Server.* ..... so which edition of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**While AlwaysOn/Availability Groups are a welcome edition to SQL Standard Edition 2016, the GUI is not supported for group creation. Try using the T-SQL code to create the group. Per Microsoft:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt614935.aspx

"To create a basic availability group, use the CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP transact-SQL command and specify the WITH BASIC option (the default is ADVANCED). For more information, see CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP (Transact-SQL). **At this time, there is no UI support to create basic availability groups in SQL Server Management Studio."**

The GUI is spamming the Advanced group used by Enterprise Edition (to your Standard Edition) while, Standard Edition only supports Basic.